# CRM 2011 Error: Sandbox Host - Access Denied

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I keep getting this error pop up on my CRM Back End Server (this back end server is assigned async and sandbox roles while the front end server has all the other roles)

```
Sandbox Host - Access Denied.
Host: CRMAP01
User: DEV\CrmAsyncService
```

I don't know why this is happening to the Async Service account (I have the sandbox service logged in as the sandbox service account)

I have tried following the instructions outlined in this blog post but it's still occurring: http://crminpractice.blogspot.com.au/2011/05/crm-2011-error-sandbox-host-access.html